# Is there a subtrait of `Index` that specifies the `len` method?

Tags: rust, traits

The [`std::ops::Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) trait is implemented by types that support array subscript notation. It appears that most types that implement `Index` also have a `len` method, but it is not part of the trait so you can't assume it exists. Therefore, I find myself writing code specialized for slices (which do have a [`len`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.len) method), but I would prefer to be more general.

Is there a subtrait of `Index` that specifies the `len` method or in some other way reveals what range of indices is allowed?

Comment: None I'm aware of; you can always make your own though.

Comment: I don't know of any type that implements `Index` and has `len` except for slices. (`Vec` and similar collections all get indexing and length by `Deref`'ing to `[T]`.)

Comment: No a subtrait (why would it be a subtrait?), but there is [`ExactSizeIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html).

Comment: @delnan, on the contrary, here is Vec's `len` method: https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/collections/up/src/libcollections/vec.rs.html#945-957

Comment: @apt1002 That's not a method of `Vec`, as I said you can only call `len` on `Vec` because of `Deref` coercions.

Comment: That is a method on Vec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a subtrait of `Index` that specifies the `len` method or in some other way reveals what range of indices is allowed?

To the best of my knowledge, not in the standard library.

---

I would note, though, that you seem to be under the misconception that:

1. `Index` necessarily returns a result for a contiguous range of keys
2. `Index` this contiguous range starts at 0

Both assumptions are necessary for `len` to be useful here (since I suppose that you are interested in checking *before* calling `[]` where the key is in present).

So, in essence, you are asking for a hierarchy of traits:

- `Index`, which allows querying for an element by key
- `RangeIndex`, which allows querying for an element by key, and guarantees that the valid keys form a contiguous range; `RangeIndex` could have a `range` method returning a `Range` of valid keys
- `ZeroBasedRangeIndex`, which allows querying for an element by numeric keys, and guarantees that the valid form a contiguous range starting from `0`; `ZeroBasedRangeIndex` could have a `len` method returning the number of valid keys

And of course those would have to be duplicated for `IndexMut`.

*Note: for example, one could implement `Index<K, Output=V>` for [`BTreeMap<K, V>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#implementations)...*

Comment: @Jacob: I've added the link.

Comment: No such misconception! I even used the word "subtrait".