# Is there a trait that works for both VecDeque and Vec?

Tags: rust, traits, random-access

We can pass a `Vec<f64>` to this function, but we cannot pass a `VecDeque`, because that is two slices:

```rust
fn mean(v: &[f64]) -> f64 {
    let sum = v.iter().sum();
    sum / v.len() as f64
}
```

Is there a trait, something perhaps analogous to a C++ `RandomAccessContainer`, that allows us to generically write code that operates on both `Vec` and `VecDeque`?

Comment: [Rust generics syntax for mean function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54168352/155423); [Implementing mean function for generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34247038/155423); [How to define sum over vectors (or iterators) in a generic way?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29459738/155423)

Comment: [Why are len() and is_empty() not defined in a trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60449514/155423); [Is there a subtrait of `Index` that specifies the `len` method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40532847/155423)

Answer (score 2):

You can just chain traits, like `Index<usize, Output = f64>` to get elements at an index, and `IntoIterator<Item = &f64>` to use `IntoIterator`. If you need `len`, then you can make your own trait and impl it.

Comment: You can also use [`ExactSizeIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html), which defines the `len` method. The values returned by `[T]::iter` and `VecDeque::iter` (and the `IntoIterator` impls on `Vec` and `VecDeque`) all implement this trait.

Comment: [Here's one way to write `mean` using `IntoIterator` and `ExactSizeIterator` so it works for `&[f64]`, `&Vec<f64>` and `&VecDeque<f64>`, as well as a bunch of other possible types.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7f91e873474cca4d6587ed1cb216be41)

Comment: On reflection, you don't even need `ExactSizeIterator` because you could just `.inspect(|_| n += 1)` the iterator as you sum over it. But that might not work in the general case.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 approaches:

1. Make your function accept a slice of slices: `fn mean(&[&[f64]]) -> f64`.
   Can be called like `mean(&[v.as_slice()])`
2. Make it accept `Iterator`. I think this it is most acceptable way to allow use both `VecDeque` and `Vec`:

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::iter::Iterator;
use std::vec::Vec;

fn mean<T: Iterator<Item = f64>>(iter: T) -> f64 {
    let (last_index, sum) = iter
        .enumerate()
        .fold((0, 0.0), |(_, sum), (i, v)| (i, sum + v));
    sum / (last_index as f64 + 1.0)
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<f64> = vec![0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0];
    println!("{:?}", mean(v.iter().copied()));
    let v: VecDeque<f64> = v.into();
    println!("{:?}", mean(v.iter().copied()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [Iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) as a parameter.

There is a good [article](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-02-iterators.html) about iterator usage.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate approach that is worth considering in these cases,
rather than looking for a trait that both types A and B implement that you
can pass into to your function, you create a new trait that both support, and use your new trait instead of the function. It usually means a little bit of duplication and boilerplate, but it is nicely extensible later.

```
trait HasMeanF64 {
    fn mean(&self) -> f64;
}

impl HasMeanF64 for &[f64] {
    fn mean(&self) -> f64 {
        self.iter().sum::<f64>() / self.len() as f64
    }
}

impl HasMeanF64 for Vec<f64> {
    fn mean(&self) -> f64 {
        self.iter().sum::<f64>() / self.len() as f64
    }
}

impl HasMeanF64 for VecDeque<f64> {
    fn mean(&self) -> f64 {
        self.iter().sum::<f64>() / self.len() as f64
    }
}
```

Now instead of writing `mean(v)` you can write `v.mean()`.

And if you still want your `mean(v)` form you can write

```
fn mean<T: HasMeanF64>(v: &T) -> f64 {
    v.mean()
}
```